# What is the target parameter mean in OSX installer?

Tags: macos, installation

Apologies in advance for my ignorance.

I'm using the `installer` on OSX because I want to automate installing some stuff on my machine. Let's say I want to install golang (the [package](https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.9.darwin-amd64.pkg)).

From [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72226/installing-pkg-with-terminal), I would think that I would be able to:

```
sudo installer -pkg go1.9.darwin-amd64.pkg -target /
```

But this doesn't seem to work as `go` is not valid command so it doesn't seem to be installed? Is this suppose to put the binary somewhere near `/`? Because I don't see any binaries there.

I looked at the manual in for `installer`.

> The target volume is specified with the -target parameter ( -tgt is accepted as a synonym).  It must
>        already be mounted when the installer command is invoked.

Well no kidding it's specified with the target parameter, but I still don't know what it *means*.

What is the target parameter and what does it *mean*, because I don't see any changes at that dir when I run it with some dir so I fail to see what the significance of this is.

Answer (score 1):

The target refers to the volume (disk), so `/` refers to the main disk, however it doesn't specify where on that disk.

Typically, installers will install a bunch of files in standard places. Apps will be in /Applications. Other executables will be in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin. Other files, depending on what they are, may go in /Library, /usr/lib, /usr/local etc.